# How to add row to end of datagridview that is filled in by a background worker inside custom control

Tags: vb.net

In the project I am working on right now, there is a tab in a custom control that is filled in after the current run finishes. So once the current run finishes, the main function calls one of the custom control's public functions that uses a background worker to fill in a datagridview in the custom control. From the main function, I want to add a row to the end of the datagridview once it is filled in. However, each time I have tried to add the row, it says the datagridview has 0 rows in it and adds it as the first item. The solution I am trying to find is how to recognize when the background worker in the custom control finishes, so I know when to add the row to the end of dgv. I thought this code would do the job, but it just loops infinitely:

```
While dgvInCustomControl.Rows.Count = 0 
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End While
```

My suspicion is that the main function is unable to determine how many rows there actually are in the datagridview, and that it will always add the row as the first item. Any help is appreciated on how to approach this problem!

Comment: You should not try to change UI controls from a BGW - that includes via subs.  Do the work in the BGW and if there if you have to, pass the data via the progress changed event using the UserState element in EventArgs

Comment: The problem is that I can't make any changes to the custom control, the code must be added to the main function. Does that leave me no options?

Comment: Does the control not raise something like the Worker Completed event?  Also is it adding rows or changing a datasource you have access to?

Comment: It does raise a worker completed event

Comment: So that will tell you when it is done ;)

Comment: so I can add an event listener from the main form that will tell me when the bgw in the custom control is finished?

Comment: *From what you describe*, yes hook up to that event. St least it should be easy to test. You might need/want a flag if you dont want to add a row every single time it uses a BGW.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. I would accept your answer if I could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could raise an event from the custom control, after the BackgroundWorker has finished. Let the main class listen to that event and do whatever it needs to do when it fires.

Just keep in mind that updating windows controls from background threads is usually not working and that you should use delegate functions to invoke the update on the main thread.

Comment: It does raise an event after it is completed, so I do have an option then.. the answers I'm getting are making me lean towards refactoring the custom control, it was preexisting